# Responsive table with first column minimum width; second column stretch; third column always at the end; how can i do that?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

#### I need a table in html

The mockup below shows which cases should be covered.

1. The table shouldn't overflow the screen, even on small devices (mobile support)
2. The first row should be as small as possible (width); The smalles width is the width of the biggest element in it
3. The second column should stretch over the rest of the space
4. The third column should be always at the end and shall be small as possible (like the first column)
5. The height of a row should be dynamic
6. All cells of a row should be in one line / should have the same height

#### I tried it already with `flex` and `table`

- With `table` i had the problem that the second column wasn't responsive (fixed table) or it overflowed the screen because the content of the second column was too big and didn't break or shrink
- With `flexbox` i didn't got the first column the same with even width different content length

#### Some specials

- The first column should contain time, the problem is that `3:00` and `10:00` haven't the same width, i don't want a static width because that would waste space or is too small for other locales
- The second column should contain items (divs (custom component called chip)) which can shrink and break if they know the maximum width
- The third column is for actions - just always at the and the width as small as possible that the second column has enough space

[image: Responsive table]

## Edit 15/01/2020

Those elements in the second column shouldn't break and the table shouldn't scroll on mobile view.
Otherwise all items in the second column should truncate.

**I already found the solution (below) but if someone have the same result without grid - you're welcome!**

Comment: When you say full width what do you mean by that?

Comment: Full width of parent container (width: 100%)

Comment: If you try to make a column 100% and add 2 other columns beside it, you will overflow.

Comment: does the left column have to be dynamic or can you assign it a static value?

Comment: it have to be dynamic

Comment: So the problem with making the first box dynamic is that the boxes won't line up if they vary in width, thus making it not a table. In that case you would build individual grids. You could however make the last box dynamic, but it would look funny. My suggestion would be, figure out what the largest size the first box would be. And then build it with grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The final solution:

**CSS Grid** (93.43% support)

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
    margin-right: .6em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.my-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content auto max-content;
    grid-gap: .6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">

    <!-- first row -->
    <span>first column</span>
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="item">some div with very looooong content that truncate</div>
        <div class="item">some div with very looooong content that truncate</div>
    </div>
    <div>here some actions</div>

    <!-- second row -->
    <span>first column</span>
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="item">some div with very looooong content that truncate</div>
        <div class="item">some div with very looooong content that truncate</div>
    </div>
    <div>here some actions</div>

</div
```

Comment: you could do that from your table using display:contents over thead/tbody and tr .

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: a responsive example , without ellipsis, because a table can be so hudge that ellipsis can be just a pain ;) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VwwweeX , other possibility for responsive , scroll ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/abboqbR  (only to tell that responsive can mean many thing ;) )

Comment: Content not visible on small screens. No scrollbar to see it. https://jsfiddle.net/712c0qhb/

Comment: i didn't dislike it. I had no  time yet to test everything. i checked that this example which i provided also don't work exactly. i have to take a look into my project.

i don't want scroll, i want that the actions always visible on mobile and i also don't want scroll on the middle column, they should break (except of one div, this should ellipse)

here is my real world example: https://imgur.com/aXOC9sG

Answer (score 1):

This html and css will match your requirements. Note that the parent `div` around the table is required.

**Update**

- You'll find a JSFiddle on https://jsfiddle.net/uwpLrd1e/
- `<th>` will center text by default. Use `text-align:left` to align it left.
- Add padding, colors and borders wherever you wish.
- Please use padding (not margin) because margin will overflow the width.

.

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>23:59</td>
        <td>Second column</td>
        <td>[]</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1:11</td>
        <td>Column 2 on row 2</td>
        <td>[X]</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

/* table wrapper is required!! */
.table-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.table-wrapper,
.table-wrapper * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table, thead, tbody, tr {
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: transparent;
}
th, td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  line-height: 1;
  hyphens: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
/* stretch middle column (of three columns) */
th:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 99.99%;
}
/* mobile support */
@media (max-width: 767.9px) {
  table {
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  }
  th, td {
    font-size: 95%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a test link?

Comment: add this html to an td: `<div style="
    white-space: nowrap;
">some dudes loooooooooooooooooooooong name</div>`

with this css: `white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;`

it doesn't work. it isnt' responsive.

Comment: The `white-space: nowrap;` never gives a responsive layout because all content will stay on one line. Only use this property if you have the consequences in mind.

Comment: I tested `<div style="white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;">some dudes loooooooooooooooooooooong name</div>` in a TD and it's fully responsive because the scrollbar on the "table X-axis" is available. This is the only way to do it within `<table>` design because stacking `<td>` cells is not possible.

Comment: Please checkout https://jsfiddle.net/3wo2umvz/2/ again. Added the `word-break: break-all` to the TD.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the **table method** without losing the responsiveness and with a second column that stretches even though its width was not specified.

In my code, the table stretches to 100% of its parent, which is the body. Make sure that the parent of your table will have a defined width.

```
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Time column</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
   <td>3:00</td>
    <td>Longer text for a longer column</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11:00</td>
    <td>Longer text for a longer column</br>and a row break</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>06:00</td>
    <td><div>Here's a div containing a <span style="color: red;">span</span></div></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: orange;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr td:first-of-type, tr td:last-of-type { 
  width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This codePen is also styled, you can test the table's responsiveness by resizing the window: https://codepen.io/ialexandru/pen/mdyKqRX

Comment: The question was not to use a static width (in % or otherwise) for the first and last column. The width of the first and last column must be the width of the widest content in it, and also respect line wrapping if there is whitespace.

Comment: I think I got it now, if you set a very low width value for first and the last column, the column will be as small as possible, but not smaller than the width of the widest word. Check the codePen from above again. It seems that it might work with a 1% width. I know you mentioned that you don't want any static value, but there must be a set width so the browser should know that those 2 columns must be very small in order to make the second one large. Try to replace the `Time column` text and the hours with one character to see how it works.

Comment: add this html to an td: `<div style=" white-space: nowrap; ">some dudes loooooooooooooooooooooong name</div>` with this css: `white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;` it doesn't work. it isn't responsive on mobile.

Comment: You won't be able to get a responsive layout out of that table using **white space: nowrap;** because the content of the div will always be written on a single line and the second column will stretch to give the text enough space to fit in.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you can try this:

```
<table class='table'>
  <thead>
    <th class='time'>time</th>
    <th class='text'>information</th>
    <th class='actions'>actions</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>04:00</td>
      <td>
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer blandit consequat dui, id lacinia est. Integer blandit, felis nec condimentum ornare, ex diam cursus leo, id rutrum dolor nibh vel libero. Integer ut augue semper, convallis libero id, finibus ipsum. Cras nec metus bibendum, dictum mi ut, ullamcorper lectus.           </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>Action</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


.table
  text-align: left
  width: 100%
  .time 
    min-width: 30px
    max-width: 50px
  .actions
    min-width: 80px //This value is a example
```

You can test: https://codepen.io/AlissonRGalindo/pen/VwYdMRm

Comment: add this html to an td: `<div style=" white-space: nowrap; ">some dudes loooooooooooooooooooooong name</div>` with this css: `white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;` it doesn't work. it isn't responsive on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can also relay on the [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) set to `auto`(default value) and set `width` to `0` for the first and last `td`, so it will expand only to the width needed by its content. the middle `td` will span the entire space left.
it requires to set a `width` to table.

example

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
  table-layout:auto;
}

th,td {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 0.25em
}

tr > :first-child,
tr > :last-child {
  width: 0 ; /* !! make sure table-layout is set to auto */
  /* white-space : nowrap; could be handy here */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input value="input"></td>
    <td> use room left</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A.1</th>
    <td> use room left</td>
    <td>(....)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>A.2</th>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>A.3</th>
    <td> use room left</td>
    <td>( / )</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
<p>to clear some question via a visual: </p>

<table>
  <tr>    
    <td>What if only 2 cells </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>

<table>
  <tr>  
    <td> </td>  
    <td>What if only 2 cells </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>

<table>
  <tr>    
    <td>What if only 1 cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout
>
> The `table-layou`t CSS property sets the algorithm used to lay out `<table>` cells, rows, and columns.
>
> **auto**
>
> By default, most browsers use an automatic table layout algorithm. **The widths of the table and its cells are adjusted to fit the content.**

Comment: add this html to an td: `<div style=" white-space: nowrap; ">some dudes loooooooooooooooooooooong name</div>` with this css: `white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;` it doesn't work. it isnt' responsive.

Comment: yeah, id dind't expect it. but i need a solution for it. i postet a solution which is using grid layout instead of flex or table.

Comment: @DanielDäschle if your content deserve a table structure, grid can still be applied to it ;)